# How can I count reactions and then announce the post with the most thumbs up?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I created a bot for my server called "Meme of the day!" and it allows users to do `m!submit <image>` and the bot reacts with thumbs up and thumbs down.
A lot of people suggest making the bot automatically count the thumbs up and post it in the announcement channel. I have no idea how I would do this.

```js
if (command === "submit") {
  if (timeout.has(message.author.id)) {
    message.channel.send("You can only submit one meme a day! " + message.author);
  } else {
    message.react("")
    message.react("")
  }
  timeout.add(message.author.id);
  setTimeout(() => {
    timeout.delete(message.author.id);
  }, 43200000);
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain more exactly what is your problem because I want to help you but don't really get what's your question...?

Comment: Okay right now you can submit an image and the bot reacts with  and  users can then vote what meme/image is the best. Every day I have to go through and see which post has the most upvotes, I'm looking for a way so the meme with the most  will be posted in an announcements channel automatically so I don't have to go through and post it myself.

Comment: You have to store all message ids of all memes sent in a channel. Then you have to set a timeout and get all message.reactions and check which has the most reactions.